# Sony Xperia Ray Superuser?

Tags: bloatware, system-apps

I have managed to unlock the bootloader and flash the phone with a custom ROM (3.0) I can now disable the many app's I don't want but I can't delete them...How do I go about getting access/permissions to do so?

Comment: Have you seen our fine [bloatware tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/bloatware/info)? It's pointing to the required answers, amongst others ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your device is rooted now you may use [titanium backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=tr). It has freeze feature beside uninstall system apps (freeze is similar with uninstall but it is reversable)

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work...told me my phone isn't rooted, yet the bootloader is open and I flashed a custom ROM onto it yesterday...

Comment: The custom ROM might have root access disabled by default (I know CyanogenMod offers that, for example). Have you checked its settings?

Comment: Do you have SuperSU installed on the device? When you open it what happens? You may need to install it, it is on Play Store but you can also flash the Zip. Google chainfire SuperSU and see what you need to do. You may be rooted, but not have Super User permission!